# Post multiple hyperlinks with an anchor text to a facebook wall via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to make a post to my facebook wall from my windows application. The post must have multiple links embeded within the post content. I can do it using Grap API but the problem is that I cannot specify an anchor text for links. The links themselves are very long so it's absolutly necessary for us to have an anchor text. But it seems facebook does not understand [anchor text](http://link) tags.

I know there is a "link" object but it's not an option because it allows only one "link" object per post.

Is there any way to post multiple links with an anchor text within a single post via Graph API?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

You can use a **Link** object, in which case you can supply a Message, Title, Description and Caption, but you can't actually hide the link, or display different text on your link - Facebook will always control how your hyperlinks work.

Other messages and Posts are plain text, so you can't use HTML formatting elements either.

It's all done to reduce the potentially hideous display of messages posted to Facebook, and to protect users from disingenuous link texts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Facebook Notes feature instead. Facebook Notes fully support HTML.

Answer (score 0):

See this. How spotify have done this if formatting html elements are not allowed.[image]

Comment: Spotify aren't publishing to the user feed, they are using the Open Graph API to achieve this. See here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook notes really support HTML. So yo can post links like this:
[03131991saty](http://www.google.com)